# How do I set up WCF security between client and server that I control?

Tags: .net, wcf, security

I have a windows service that is hosting a WCF service and a WPF application that communicates with it.  The WPF application will be on a different machine on the same network.  I am having trouble with setting up security between the two when sending WCf messages.  Here are the Server and Client app.config files:

Server

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <configuration>
      <system.serviceModel>
        <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="WCFBehavior" name="WCF.WCFService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
          name="NetTcpBindingEndpoint" contract="WCF.IWCFService">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
          name="MexTcpBindingEndpoint" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:8731/WCFService/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="WebHttp">
          <webHttp />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="WCFBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
          <serviceTimeouts transactionTimeout="05:05:00" />
          <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="500" maxConcurrentSessions="500"
            maxConcurrentInstances="2147483647" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
      <wsDualHttpBinding>
        <binding name="WCFBinding">
          <security mode="None">
          </security>
        </binding>
      </wsDualHttpBinding>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="webHttpBindingWithJsonP" crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true" />
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
  </startup>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <probing privatePath="lib" />
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Client

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
  </startup>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <probing privatePath="lib" />
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <netTcpBinding>
        <binding name="NetTcpBindingEndpoint" closeTimeout="00:01:05"
          openTimeout="00:00:05" receiveTimeout="00:00:20" sendTimeout="00:00:20"
          transactionFlow="false" transferMode="Buffered" transactionProtocol="OleTransactions"
          hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" listenBacklog="10" maxBufferPoolSize="524288"
          maxBufferSize="65536" maxConnections="10" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
            maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"
            enabled="false" />
          <security mode="None">
          </security>
        </binding>
      </netTcpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:8731/WCFService/" binding="netTcpBinding"
        bindingConfiguration="NetTcpBindingEndpoint" contract="WCFServiceReference.IWCFService"
        name="NetTcpBindingEndpoint">
        <identity>
          <dns value="localhost" />
        </identity>
      </endpoint>
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

The only way I am able to have the client connect successfully to the service is if I create a user on the server with the same username and password as the account I am using on the client machine.  How can I set up security to avoid this?  Since I have control over both the client and the server I am not concerned with having a high level of security.

Answer (score 0):

You could set up a database with the user credentials on the server. And to authenticate the user request you can create a user on the server dynamically if the user credentials from the client are validated off the database server.

Comment: How does that help if the CredentialType is Windows?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want CredentialType of UserName.  Right now you are getting the default Windows.

[Authentication, Authorization, and Identities in WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647503.aspx)